# How can I fake/mock/spy the a service in component test to avoid the NullInjectorError with Angular 9 / Jasmine / Karma?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, dependency-injection, jasmine, karma-jasmine

In my Angular app I need to test my component which use a `UserService` service. This `UserService` extends the `ProxyService` which extends `RemoteDataService`. This `RemoteDataService` uses `HttpClient`.

This is the component's code:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-tax-type-list',
  templateUrl: './tax-type-list.component.html',
})
export class TaxTypeListComponent {
  userService = AppModule.InjectorInstance.get<UserService>(UserService);

  constructor() { }

  // ...
}
```

**user.service.ts**

```js
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UserService extends ProxyService<UserInterface> {

  constructor() {
    super(new User());
  }

  getCurrentUser(): UserInterface {
    return new User().init(localStorage.getItem('user'));
  }
}
```

**proxy.service.ts**

```js
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ProxyService<T> extends RemoteDataService<T> {
  constructor(
    private instance: T,
  ) {
    super(instance);
  }

  // ...
}
```

**remote-data.service.ts**

```js
export class DataService<T> {
  private http: HttpClient;

  constructor(model: T) {
    this.http = AppModule.InjectorInstance.get<HttpClient>(HttpClient);
  }
  // ...
}
```

Here is my test:

```js
describe('TaxTypeListComponent', () => {
  let component: TaxTypeListComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<TaxTypeListComponent>;

  // set TestBed before each tests
  beforeAll(async(() => {
    TestBed.initTestEnvironment(BrowserDynamicTestingModule, platformBrowserDynamicTesting());
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        // angular testing module that provides mocking for http connections
        HttpClientTestingModule,
        RouterTestingModule,
      ],
      // add declaration of services or components and use inject to get to them in tests
      providers: [
        Injector,
        {provide: HelperFactoryService, useValue: new TaxType() },
      ],
      declarations: [
        TaxTypeListComponent,
      ],
    }).compileComponents();

    AppModule.InjectorInstance = TestBed;
    TestBed.inject(HelperFactoryService);
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TaxTypeListComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    component.userService = new UserService();
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

And now I get this error message:

```
NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[UserService -> HttpClient -> HttpClient]:
  NullInjectorError: No provider for HttpClient!
error properties: Object({ ngTempTokenPath: null, ngTokenPath: [ 'UserService', 'HttpClient', 'HttpClient' ] })
```

How can I fake/mock/spy the `UserService` to avoid the NullInjectorError?

Comment: Why are you not injecting `UserService` in constructor of component `TaxTypeListComponent ` ?

Comment: this is just an example code, and because in my real app it's an abstract class where I want to avoid unnecessary parameters in `super()` call

Comment: Well, I am not sure if my suggested approach will work but have u tried using `useClass` . something like  : https://medium.com/@shashankvivek.7/testing-a-component-with-stub-services-and-spies-in-jasmine-1428d4242a49  .  Let me know the outcome, I'll try to think on it accordingly.  I have never tested on something like before.